# global values data not persisting

Tags: android

In my adapter class, I have used two global variables.

public static String prevYearSelected = "",currentYearSelected = "";

if my method, based on two conditions I am assigning the values to the two variables.

Code:

```
public static String prevYearSelected = "",currentYearSelected = "";

if (selectedMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("01")) {

    if(isCurrentYearSelected == true)
    {
        currentYearSelected = selectedDate + " " + "Januari" + " " + selectedYear;
    }
    else
    {
        prevYearSelected = selectedDate + " " + "Januari" + " " + selectedYear + " " + "-";
    }
    selectedDateTV.setText(prevYearSelected+currentYearSelected);
}
if (selectedMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("02")) {
    if(isCurrentYearSelected == true)
    {
        currentYearSelected = selectedDate + " " + "Februari" + " " + selectedYear;

    }
    else
    {
        prevYearSelected = selectedDate + " " + "Februari" + " " + selectedYear + " " + "-";
    }
    selectedDateTV.setText(prevYearSelected+currentYearSelected);
}
```

Actually based on the year selection in the calendar I am passing the value to the global parameters. For ex if I selected 2018 March 5th then I am passing that value in the current year selected ans similarly if I select 2017 March 8th, then I am passing that value to prevYearSelected.

But the issue is when i am setting both the values to the `textview` it is displaying one of the value is null...i.e if I select 2017 date the current value is showing null and if i select 2018 date then it is showing prev value is null. I really don't understand why global variables are returning a null value instead of persisting the data.

I will be really thank ful for help on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
public static String prevYearSelected = "",currentYearSelected = "";

if (selectedMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("01")) {

    if(isCurrentYearSelected == true)
    {
        currentYearSelected = selectedDate + " " + "Januari" + " " + selectedYear;
        prevYearSelected = selectedDate + " " + "Januari" + " " + (selectedYear - 1) + " " + "-";
    }
    else
    {
        prevYearSelected = selectedDate + " " + "Januari" + " " + selectedYear + " " + "-";
        currentYearSelected = selectedDate + " " + "Januari" + " " + (selectedYear + 1);
    }
    selectedDateTV.setText(prevYearSelected+currentYearSelected);
}
if (selectedMonth.equalsIgnoreCase("02")) {
    if(isCurrentYearSelected == true)
    {
        currentYearSelected = selectedDate + " " + "Februari" + " " + selectedYear;
        prevYearSelected = selectedDate + " " + "Februari" + " " + (selectedYear - 1) + " " + "-";
    }
    else
    {
        prevYearSelected = selectedDate + " " + "Februari" + " " + selectedYear + " " + "-";
        currentYearSelected = selectedDate + " " + "Februari" + " " + (selectedYear + 1);
    }
    selectedDateTV.setText(prevYearSelected+currentYearSelected);
}
```